# How to make compound promises execute asynchronously

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I have two promises compounded to abstract away all the bluetooth scanning logic in my mobile application written in Typescript, for Nativescript. I have the promise returned from a function I import into my  HomeComponent. I want the `then` in my HomeComponent to run only after all the logic in my scan routine is completed, at the moment, it runs as soon as the scan has started.

#### ble.scan.ts:

```
import * as dialogs from "ui/dialogs";
import * as bluetooth from "nativescript-bluetooth";

var devices: Array<bluetooth.Peripheral>;
var _peripheral: bluetooth.Peripheral;

export function scan() {
    return bluetooth.hasCoarseLocationPermission().then(
        (granted) => {
            if (!granted) {
                bluetooth.requestCoarseLocationPermission();
            } else {
                bluetooth.scan({
                }).then(() => {
                    console.log("scanning complete");
                    if (this.devices == undefined) {
                        return null;
                    }
                    console.log("2"); // ************** SECOND ****************
                }, (err) => {
                    console.log("error while scanning: " + err);
                });
            }
        });
}
```

#### Home.Component.ts:

```
console.log("1"); // ************** FIRST ****************
this._ble.scan().then(
     // Log the fulfillment value
    function (val) {
        console.log("3"); // ************** THIRD ****************
         _this.addClicked = toggleAdd(_this.page, _this, _this.addClicked); //toggle button
        _this.Connect(val);                
    })
```

How can I make these run in order?

## Update:

In response to the duplicate comments, The linked answer seems to be about multiple then's executing after one another. My issue is about then's on different levels, e.g. I want the HomeComponent `then` to execute **after** the ble.scan `then`. In the linked answer, it is about multiple then's on the same level?

So I would like the 3 console.log's in my code to print out in order, i.e. 1,2,3 regardless of how long any of the calls etc. take. I am currently getting 1,3,2 - i.e. the third log is called as soon as te promise has been created, not when it has been resolved.

Update:

Taking the exact example from the linked question, I have:

```
test() {
    addElement("first")
        .then(
            function (val){
                addElement("second");
                console.log("second.");
            })
            .then(
            function (val){
                addElement("third");
                console.log("third.");
            });
}


export function addElement(elementText){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log(elementText);
            resolve();
        }, Math.random() * 2000);
    });
}
```

I would like these functions to print out, `first, second., second, third., third`. However, I get:

> JS: first
>   JS: second.
>   JS: third.
>   JS: third
>   JS: second

How do I get the `then` to execute after the called promises' then has completed?

Comment: @naomik I really can't see how that duplicate fits here?

Comment: @Bergi the entire question to me reads "How do i make these [promises] run in order?" which has been answered before on SO. If you don't think it's a match, please re-open it. I highly respect/value your input here.

Comment: @naomik Thanks for the link, but I am not sure it's the same issue, I have updated my question

Comment: What do you mean by "separate levels", that is not an idiomatic JavaScript term? I have to agree with @naomik, this still reads like *I need to guarantee the promises execute in order*, either way the duplicate answers that regardless.

Comment: Why don't you break the code in the first `then` into two blocks: in the first `then` check if the permission has been granted, in case it has not, return the `grant permission promise`. In the chained `then` put all the `bluetooth` code (else branch) and then `catch` the exception in case it cannot grant the requested permissions.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson please see my update, which I hope shows why the linked question doesn't produce the behaviour I am after

Comment: you should delete all the unnecessary stuff at the top now, that is a bunch of code that had dependancies nobody else has and honestly probably does not care about, a generic MCVE will get you more than highly localized code.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Thanks for the tip, I have posted a new questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37556241/ensuring-asyncronous-then-execution-in-compound-promises