# Ensuring asyncronous '.then()' execution in compound promises

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I am using Typescript to write JS promises. I have a compound promise, i.e. promise which returns a promise
I have:

```
test() {
    addElement("first")
        .then(
            function (val){
                addElement("second");
                console.log("second*);
            })
            .then(
            function (val){
                addElement("third");
                console.log("third*");
            });
}


export function addElement(elementText){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        setTimeout(function(){
            resolve();
        }, Math.random() * 2000);
    })
    .then(console.log(elementText));
}
```

I would like these functions to print out, `first, second*, second, third*, third`. However, I get:

> JS: first
>   JS: second*
>   JS: third*
>   JS: third
>   JS: second

How do I get the `then` to execute after the called promises' `then` has completed?

Comment: Promises are resolved on next iteration of the event loop, by design.

Comment: @zerkms Is there a way to execute some code only after all the addElement logic is executed? Like an onCompletion event?

Comment: You can use Promise.all() that also would take in count the execution order.

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards yes there is - use `.then()`

Comment: First off, change `.then(console.log(elementText));` to `.then(function() {console.log(elementText)})` so it is not called immediately, but is instead called when the promise resolves.  You need to pass a function reference to `.then()`.  You were executing the function immediately and then passing the return result of that function which is `undefined`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make compound promises execute asynchronously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534070/how-to-make-compound-promises-execute-asynchronously)

Answer (score 0):

You're not *returning* your promise in the `then` block. If you don't return the promise, then the `then` block will `return undefined` immediately, and nothing will wait for it. If you return a promise instead, then execution of the promise chain will pause until the promise you return has been satisfied.

```
test() {
    addElement("first")
        .then(
            function (val){
                console.log("second*");
                return addElement("second");
            })
            .then(
            function (val){
                console.log("third*");
                return addElement("third");
            });
}
```

Though I don't personally consider it a "rookie mistake", your description matches "Rookie Mistake #5" in Nolan Lawson's "[We have a problem with promises](https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html)"; read on for a more in-depth explanation.